# How to setup azure monitor for PHP application

Tags: azure, monitoring

I am a newbie to azure

I have a web(PHP) application that is hosted in UKCloud. The os we are using is ubuntu. How can I integrate azure monitoring for it?

I had a look at the [ApplicationInsights-PHP](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP) package but this seems to be archived.  How can I use app insights for PHP-based applications?

Is there any document that I can refer to integrate the azure monitor with my application

Comment: Can you clarify what you're going for here? Your application is hosted externally to Azure (in "*UKCloud*"), but you're trying to use Azure Monitor to monitor it?

Comment: @esqew Yes i would like to use the azure service in order to monitor my application

Answer (score 0):

according to official documentation, PHP and WordPress are not supported

PHP and WordPress sites are not supported. There is currently no officially supported SDK/agent for server-side monitoring of these workloads. However, manually instrumenting client-side transactions on a PHP or WordPress site by adding the client-side JavaScript to your web pages can be accomplished by using the JavaScript SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like there is support for opentelemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-overview) though.
There are [many libraries](https://packagist.org/?query=opentelemetry) in active development/maintenance for this